# Windows GDI Context- LoadImage and GetLastError()

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

A call to `LoadImage()` in the first steps of my program returns NULL. Just after it, `GetLastError()` is called, and it surprisingly returns 0.
I wondered why `LoadImage()` is failing, since `GetLastError()` clearly reveals that no error code is set after the failed function.
This is a snippet of the code:

```
if ( (hbitmap = (HBITMAP) LoadImage(hThisInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(MY_BITMAP), 
                                    IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, 
                                    LR_CREATEDIBSECTION)) == NULL) 
    printf("Last error: %d\n", GetLastError());
```

With HBITMAP hbitmap, HINSTANCE hThisInstance (argument of WinMain), and MY_BITMAP a valid bitmap resource.

Comment: Hmm... what does `FindResource`return for that bitmap?

Comment: If LoadImage() is returning NULL, GetLastError() can only return 0 if another API function is called before you call GetLastError() and it clears the current error code. GetLastError() is only meaningful IMMEDIATELY after the failed function. Which makes me think the code posted is not the real code being used.

Comment: You either found a bug in Windows or we're not looking at the real code.  Given the very unhelpful error reporting, especially in a GUI app, I'll but a buck on "not the real code".

Comment: I call it immediately after it. Why should I not post the whole meaningful code? I have been stuck over this for too many hours, I want to understand why it doesn't work. To tell the truth, it also happened a similar thing once called CreateDIBSection (in another program), handling the error in the same way.

Comment: Requested size is `0 x 0` pixels and you are not requesting `LR_DEFAULTSIZE`, was this the intent?

Comment: From msdn.com: "If this flag is not specified and cxDesired and cyDesired are set to zero, the function uses the actual resource size." So if I set them to 0, and I don't specify LR_DEFAULTSIZE, I get the real image size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, `LoadImage` returns `NULL` and does not set any error when there's a problem with the file format.

A copy of the bitmap I was trying to load can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RqDe.png). I created it using GIMP, which in the current version is quite buggy.

The solution was to open the file in Paint and save it again. Now `LoadImage` loads the image without any complaints.

Comment: Weird. You called `GetLastError`? What did it return? `0`?

Comment: when exporting using GIMP v2.8.6 or later select 'Do Not Write Color Space Information' from the 'Compatibility' options treeview of the 'Export Image as BMP' dialog...

Answer (score 3):

I found exactly the same behaviour with the latest version of GIMP.
When you're doing an export from Gimp, select the Compatibility Options [+] button and check the "Do not write colourspace information" checkbox, and the bitmap will load OK using LoadImage. Edit: I see a prior comment to that effect now, otherwise I might not have bothered writing!

Comment: I had not used GIMP to create the image, but it turned out that I did need to open it in GIMP and re-export without colorspace so that LoadImage accepts the file. Thanks that it was answered here or it would have been very hard to find out.