# Windows GDI Context - Function fails and GetLastError() returns 0

Tags: c++, windows, gdi

Is it possible for a Windows API function to fail, and then, just after it, GetLastError() return 0?
I don't think that showing some code or not really matters: in which cases does it happen?

```
if ( !(hbmp = (HBITMAP) LoadImage(hThisInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IMG), 
       IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION)))
    printf("Last error: %d\n", GetLastError());
```

With:
HBITMAP hbmp
HINSTANCE hThisInstance
IMG bitmap resource

Comment: Are you **sure** that you aren't doing anything else in between? Are you using any macros?

Comment: I am just using printf("Last error: %d", GetLastError()), which is not a windows API... So it is not relevant.

Comment: Which function are you calling? Is that function *documented* to set the last-error value?

Comment: I am calling LoadImage. It is documented: as a matter of fact, it first made GetLastError() return 1814; then, I modified an argument and it made GetLastError() return 0, failing though.

Comment: A typical situation is that you have other API calls between your `LoadImage` and `GetLastError`, e.g. CRT calls which internally involve API calls, and you are actually losing correct error code.

Comment: Win32 API functions only set the last-error value if they actually *fail* (in the case of `LoadImage`, if it returns `NULL`). If the function succeeds, the last-error value is *not* set and retains whatever value it had before the function was called. It would really help if you showed your code, then we wouldn't need to ask so many basic questions.

Comment: I posted the whole code. By the way, thank you for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LoadImage() returns NULL and GetLastError() returns 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242193/loadimage-returns-null-and-getlasterror-returns-0)

Comment: Greg Hegwill: No, it is not a duplicate. I checked that topic before posting my question: I call LoadImage() at the initialization of my program, so this is not definitely the case.

Comment: This is, howvever, a duplicate of this question instead: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/7947560/windows-gdi-context-loadimage-and-getlasterror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem to reside in my bitmap image 32 bits encoding. `LoadImage()` fails without setting an error code while trying to load it, though. I definitely think it should be considered as a error handling inaccuracy within `LoadImage()` itself, notwithstanding any warning about such constraints possibly claimed in online documentation.

Comment: Can you post the image somewhere so we can duplicate your findings?

Comment: I had the same problem. The image is here: http://www.rundfunkband.ch/tmp/spin03.bmp